# RFID Card Data sending from arduino ide to xampp failure

Tags: xampp, web-development-server, rfid, arduino-ide, data-transfer

I am trying to send data from an ESP32 microcontroller using RFID to a PHP script hosted on XAMPP. I am using the Arduino IDE to program the ESP32 and HTTPClient library to make the HTTP request to the PHP script. However, I am unable to send the data successfully. I have tried multiple variations of the code, but I still can't get it to work.

I am using the correct SSID and password to connect to the WiFi, and the code compiles without any errors. However, when I check the PHP script, it doesn't receive any data. I have checked the XAMPP logs, but there are no errors related to this.

Here is my code:

```c
Created on: April 3, 2023 • Updated on: April 3, 2023 • 0 views
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "TP-Link_C028";
const char* password = "16810112";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin("http://localhost/script.php");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String postData = "data=" + input;

    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(postData);

    if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
      String response = http.getString();
      Serial.println(response);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error sending data: " + http.errorToString(httpResponseCode));
    }

    http.end();
  }
}
```

What's the issue?

Comment: http://freenotes.org/note/DkvNB

Here is my code, please help me

Comment: Try replacing `localhost` with the IP of the XAMPP server.